# how to less the javascript lines instead of repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi all am using j query for my front end development am pretty newbie to js to write a maintainable js my question is is there any possible way to write single click event function for every element in html because evey time am using id of every element. like this.

html

```
<a id="get-in" class="">Login
  <div class="log-n-contanier">
      <form id="login">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" />
         <br>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
         <br>
<button class="btn blue med large" id="login-trigger">LOGIN</button>
<span id="forgot-trigger">forgot password?</span>
</form>
<form id="forgot">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" />
        <br>
    <button class="btn blue med large">Send Instructions</button>
    <span id="cancel-trigger">cancel</span>
    </form>
    </div>
</a>

$('button, a').click(function(){
     ids=$(this).attr('id');
     if(ids=='get-in'){

        $('.log-n-contanier').show();
        $(this).addClass('active');
     }
        else if(ids=='login-trigger')
        {
            alert('you were loggging');
        }
        else if(ids=='forgot-trigger'){
            $('#login').hide();
            $('#forgot').show();
        }
        else if(ids=='cancel-trigger'){
            $('#forgot').hide();
            $('#login').show();
        }
        else{
            alert('over');
        }
     });
```

how to minify code using `event bindings` etc..? because every tym i need to write the id names or class names..! is that rightway to write or is there any other way..?

Comment: binding event with html elements should be specific. better u avoid `$('button, a')` and use `$('#get-in,#login-trigger,#forgot-trigger,#cancel-trigger')`.

Comment: @I.P can you give any samples..?

Comment: don't put so much code in the event handler.  Give each button and link its own event handler, and _then_ worry about refactoring the resulting code.

Comment: @Alnitak should i go with I.P way..?

Comment: @vikranth..just bind `$('#get-in,#login-trigger,#forgot-trigger,#cancel-trigger').click(function(){ //your logic here });` . this makes DOM to search for the specific ids instead all buttons amd anchors.

Comment: @VikranthVivek..as a newbie u can follow this now but you will understand event binding, good logic writing and Alnitak, krasimir advices which are all effective in future.

Comment: @VikranthVivek no, you shouldn't go with I.P's recommendation.  You should bind a separate event handler for each specific button, e.g. `$('#get-in').on('click', ...)`

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest to cache the objects returned by jQuery. It's better from a performance point of view and also improves the readability. For example, instead of repeating *$('#forgot')* again and again you should write:

```
var forgotButton = $('#forgot');
...
forgotButton.hide();
```

Using this approach you may place all the jquery-referencing at the top of your code. Later if you decide to switch to another library you will have to make changes only on one place.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of repetition you have is so small that you shouldn't worry about it.

However what you *should* do is register a separate event handler for each link, thus allowing your browser to dispatch events directly to the right handlers, instead of writing a whole series of `if (id === ...)` branches:

```
$('#get-in').on('click', function(){
    $('.log-n-contanier').show();
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$(#'login-trigger').on('click', function() {
    alert('you were loggging');
});

$('#forgot-trigger').on('click', function() {
    $('#login').hide();
    $('#forgot').show();
});

$('#cancel-trigger').on('click', function() {
    $('#forgot').hide();
    $('#login').show();
});
```

*Don't* worry about refactoring any of this unless the repetition within the functions becomes unwieldy.

Note also that I always use `.on('click', ...)` rather than `.click` to emphasise that this is an event *registration* call, and not an event *trigger* call.